# WCF Service Store and Manipulate Collection?

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I'm working on a project where I have to store data in a WCF service but I'm unsure how I can maintain the changes when the data is manipulated.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode =
InstanceContextMode.Single,UseSynchronizationContext = true)]
public class TestService : ITestService {
    private List<TestClass> cl;

    public TestService()
    {
        cl = new List<TestClass>();
        TestClass tc = new TestClass(5);
        cl.add(tc);
    }

    public void Diminish(int x)
    {
         cl[0].Value -= x;
    }

    public TestClass ReturnValue(int p)
    {
        return cl[p];
    }
}
```

So now when a client uses this service how can I send an updated value of the collection `cl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a static field. But obviously once you do that you need to synchronize the access to it because the `List<T>` class is not thread safe:

```
public class TestService : ITestService {
    private static List<TestClass> cl;
    private static object _syncRoot = new object();

    static TestService()
    {
        cl = new List<TestClass>();
        TestClass tc = new TestClass(5);
        cl.Add(tc);
    }

    public void Diminish(int x)
    {
         lock (_syncRoot)
         {
             cl[0].Value -= x;
         }
    }

    public TestClass ReturnValue(int p)
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            return cl[p];
        }
    }
}
```

or you could also use the [`SynchronizedCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668265.aspx) class which is thread safe:

```
public class TestService
{
    private static SynchronizedCollection<TestClass> cl;

    static TestService()
    {
        cl = new SynchronizedCollection<TestClass>();
        TestClass tc = new TestClass(5);
        cl.Add(tc);
    }

    public void Diminish(int x)
    {
        cl[0].Value -= x;
    }

    public TestClass ReturnValue(int p)
    {
        return cl[p];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using private static SynchronizedCollection<TestClass> cl; but when I returnvalue(0) after having run the diminish i still get 5 and not 4.

Comment: @JohnDoe, any chance you restarted the service in between the two calls? Because since you are storing the list in memory everytime you recompile and run the WCF service it will reinitialize its values. If you want to persist this list in a durable manner you might consider storing it in a file or a database instead of leaving it in-memory of the server.

Comment: Service is running, I'm running two instances of vs2010 one with the service one with the client.

Comment: [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,UseSynchronizationContext = true)]  added that to the service but now if i try to run diminsh it subtracts more than it should

Comment: It seems that if I use the constructor public TestService() that I have to use the ServiceBehavior decoration for it to work.